# What is equivalent to mozPaintCount in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox [mozPaintCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.mozPaintCount) returns the number of times the current document has been painted to the screen in this window. What is the equivalent property in Chrome ? If Chrome does not give it directly, is there any alternate way of computing it ?

Comment: Nothing equivalent to it is implemented in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65348

Comment: you can use the inspector to see the refresh rate if that helps

Comment: Is it same as counting how many times the page is refreshed?

Comment: @dr_dev It is not how many time the url was reloaded (or the page was refreshed). You can check http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/ to know more about repaint, reflow.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify exactly what it is you want to do with that 'paint count', if you can get it? It may not be possible to emulate it precisely, but if you just need a way to determine if the document is in view (by detecting a more frequent update of 'paint count') you could overlay you document with a transparent element containing a Flash Player running a small Flash application (swf) that reports its own framerate to the page via ExternalInterface.

Comment: This should be the comment